# minimal prime generator C

Tags: c

I have to create a minimal prime generator in C (we need the minimal primes that have at least two digits) and i cannot use tables.So my thought was first find all the primes,second with using masks to find all the subsequences of each number and finally check if every subsequence is not a prime number.i cannot find the minimal primes because i didnt put a condition to check if a subsequence is prime or no?(my code is not ready so it may have some mistakes but it runs)
my code

```
    #include <stdio.h>

#define MAXNUMB 100

int main () 
{
    int i,j,x,mask,max=1,mult,sub;
    for (i = 11 ; i < MAXNUMB; i += 2 ) {

        for (j = 3; j * j <= i; j += 2) {  
           if (i % j == 0) { 
               break; 
           }           
        }
        if (j * j > i) {


            int length = 0;
            int tmp=i;
            while (tmp != 0) {
                tmp /= 10;
                length++;
            }


           for (x=1;x<length*2;x++) {
              mask=x;
              mult=1;
              sub=0;
              int num=i;
              while ( num != 0 ) {
                  if ( mask % 2 == 1 ) {
                      sub += num % 10 * mult;
                      mult *= 10; 
                   }
                   num /= 10;
                   mask /= 2;

                }


             printf ("%d \n",sub);

           }
          printf ("%d is minimal prime \n",i);
       }  


    }
}
```

Comment: There are [only 26 minimal primes in base 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_prime_%28recreational_mathematics%29). Unless this is homework, use a table.

Comment: this is homework and it is prohibited for us to use a table

Comment: @kostasdi Ok, what's your question?

Comment: @Schwern i cannot figure out how to check if the subsequence is prime or not?i do it like i did with the numbers(with for loop)or it is an easier and faster way that i cannot see *i dont ask for code because i cannot learn this way but something more like a guide*

Comment: @kostasdi What does it mean for a subsequence to be prime?

Comment: @personjerry for example 881 is a minimal prime because 8,8,1,88,81,81 which are all his subsequences are not primes.But 109 is not a minimal prime because 19 which is one of 109 subsequences is a prime number

Comment: I'm not sure what you think the innermost `for` loop is doing, but `for (x=1;x<combs-1;x++) mask=x;` is the extent of the loop. It is not clear to me that's useful. If you want more statements in the body of the loop, you need to add braces around the statements. You definitely need a function to test whether a number is prime; you need another function to find the various subsequences of a number to test whether any of those subsequences is prime. The fact that you can't use a table simply makes the prime checking code slower. Apart from 2 and 3, every prime number is has the form 6N±1.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler maybe i was not clear..it is prohibited for us to use tables because this is a project in the university.so you are telling me that i forgot to use braces in this `for (x=1;x<combs-1;x++)` loop or the loop is not usefull at all?

Comment: I recognize that you're under an artificial constraint not to use tables.  That's OK — computer courses seem to do that sort of thing.  Regarding the loop: as written, it is a complicated way of writing `if (combs > 2) mask = combs - 2;`.  If that's not what you intended, then you forgot some braces or otherwise need to revisit that loop.  I"m not sure what it is going on in your code; it doesn't have a separate function that generates sub-sequences of the digits in the target number, nor a separate function that checks whether a number is prime.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler so it is better to use a function like this `int IsPrime(int number) { int i; for (i=3; i*i<number; i+=2) { if (number % i == 0 ) return 0; } return 1; } ` to check first the numbers and then the sub sequences if are primes or no so i can find all the minimal primes?

Comment: I'm tolerably certain you need an `IsPrime()` function — yes.  The one you've proposed function doesn't handle composite numbers 4, 6, 8, 10, 14, … correctly; it reports they are prime.  But the concept of a function to test primality is correct.  You then apply it to numbers in the range 11 .. 100000; if the number is prime, then you go on a rampage to find whether all the single digits are non-prime (if a 2, 3, 5 or 7 appears, it is not a minimal prime), followed by processing for each pair of digits (if the number has at least 3), then each triple of digits (if the number has at least 4).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the concept to use this counter `i+=2` is that all the  even numbers are not primes...did i miss something?btw thank you for your advice

Comment: Well, when I use the `IsPrime()` you showed in a simple test program that checks the primality of the numbers 2-29, it identifies that all these are 'prime': 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 22, 23, 25, 26, 28, 29.  A fair number of those are not normally considered prime.  You could claim that it only handles odd numbers (but then you should write `assert(number % 2 == 1);` to enforce that), but you still have a problem that 9 and 25 are claimed to be prime — the `<` needs to be `<=`.

Answer (score 0):

If MAXNUMB is not too large then you can very quickly find all the primes until MAXNUMB using the [Sieve_of_Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). After you have that you can get every subsequence of an n-digit number by counting from 1 to 2^n-1 and use the bit-pattern of the current count to specify the current subsequence. Check each subsequence in the sieve.

If MAXNUMB is too big then you can build the sieve up to sqrt(MAXNUMB), so that when you test a number whether it's prime or not you just have to check whether it's divisible with any prime, instead of checking whether it's divisible any odd number.

Comment: my MAXNUMB is 100000000.i can find the prime numbers using sqrt(i) and i use a counter i+=2 because even numbers are no primes(i started from i=11 and it goes 11,13,15 etc)but the problem is not to find the prime numbers but how i can find if the subsequences of a prime number if is it prime or not

Comment: just create a function that takes one argument (a number) and returns true/false depending on whether that number is prime or not. So first you call this function for some number n, and if n is prime then call this function for every subsequence as well until you have checked that all subsequences are composite numbers or you have found one that's prime.

Comment: i am not sure i can handle functions very well..because i am a begginer and this lesson is"introduction to programming"but i will try it.thank you

Comment: my function can be like that?
`int IsPrime(int number) {
    int i;
    for (i=11; i*i<number; i+=2) {
        if (number % i == 0 ) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}`

Comment: Almost. True, you are interested only in primes greater than 10, but when you test whether 'number' is prime or not, you have to start 'i' from 3. (And assume that 'number' will always be odd.) You will not have an overflow because MAXNUMB is not too large.

Comment: and i can use the same function so i can check if the subsequences of a prime are primes (after i found them by using mask)???

Comment: ok thank you.only one last question.My code will be easier or faster by using the function than try to do it without functions and without tables(because i started that way as you can see in my code in the question)

Comment: Your code will definitely be cleaner and easier with the function. As far as tables... If you think of a table of all minimal primes then that would be the fastest (obviously :-). Otherwise the fact that you use a function to find out whether a number is prime or not is sort of orthogonal to using tables. You could precompute the Sieve of Eratosthenes into a table, and use that table in your function. That would significantly speed up your code.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has a nice [pseudocode algorithm for primality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Pseudocode).  It's naive, but it works.

```
function is_prime(n : integer)
    if n ≤ 1
        return false
    else if n ≤ 3
        return true
    else if n mod 2 = 0 or n mod 3 = 0
        return false
    let i ← 5
    while i×i ≤ n
        if n mod i = 0 or n mod (i + 2) = 0
            return false
        i ← i + 6
    return true
```

I'll leave translating this into C for you.  My one note is that `i` should be of a type larger than `n`'s type.  For the reason, consider what happens to `i×i ≤ n` when `n` is the largest integer.

When you're ready, you can look at [my solution to this problem](https://gist.github.com/schwern/5aeff6287d2d2f100736).

Comment: so you say that i must put something like `long i;`

Comment: @kostasdi Yes, but it's not safe to assume that `long` is bigger than `int`.  `long` is only required to be at least 32 bits and `int` is only required to be at least 16 bits.  It's safer to use [`intN_t` from stdint.h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Fixed-width_integer_types).  So `int32_t` and `int64_t`.

Comment: if i know that the maxnumb is 100000000(we define it at the beggining) i must do that?

Comment: @kostasdi If you have to ask, you don't understand why you'd need it in the first place. Walk through the algorithm using 8 bit signed integers (-128 to 127) where `n` is 127 and watch what happens to `i×i`. Also, arbitrary size limits, especially decimal ones, are a crutch.  Try writing the algorithm where the only limit is your integer size.

Comment: Also, you can avoid the integer overflow if you precompute 'sn=ceil(sqrt(n))' and then test (i <= sn) instead of testing (i*i <= n). The reason for the ceil() function is that due to numerical reason it's possible that, say, sqrt(25) is 4.99999999999 and you would not want to miss testing i==5... :-).

Comment: @kostasdi I've been learning C myself lately and I went ahead and [wrote my own solution to your problem](https://gist.github.com/schwern/5aeff6287d2d2f100736) if you're curious.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of a minimal prime is moderately interesting.  I wrote the following code to do the checking.

```
/* SO 33838621: Minimal Primes */
/*
** Find the minimal primes less than 100,000.
**
** A minimal prime is a prime number for which no subsequence of the digits
** that make up the number is itself prime.
** The question gives two examples:
** = 881 is prime and is a minimal prime because none of { 8, 8, 1, 88,
**       81, 81 } are prime.
** = 109 is prime but is not a minimal prime because { 1, 0, 9, 10, 9,
**       19 } includes the prime 19.
** Clearly, the single digit primes are all trivially minimal.
**
** Additional wrinkle: the code may not build up a table of primes.
**
** NB: All primes except 2 and 3 have the form 6N±1
*/

/*
** There are two problems to solve:
** (1) Check for primality without using a table of primes.
** (2) Generate all subsequences of a number.
** The latter problem is somewhat harder than the former.
** The surviving solution uses recursive string manipulation.
**
** NB: Command subsequences is derived from this, and helps check
**     the validity of the minimal primes.
*/

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static bool is_prime(int n)
{
    if (n < 2)
        return false;
    if (n == 2 || n == 3 || n == 5 || n == 7)
        return true;
    if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0 || n % 7 == 0)
        return false;
    for (int c = 12; (c - 1) * (c - 1) <= n; c += 6)
    {
        if (n % (c - 1) == 0 || n % (c + 1) == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

static bool has_prime_n_digit_subset(int p0, int n_digits, const char *buffer, int buflen)
{
    //printf("-->> p0 = %5d, n = %d (%s)\n", p0, n_digits, buffer);
    assert(buflen >= 0 && strlen(buffer) == (size_t)buflen);
    for (int i = 0; i < buflen; i++)
    {
        int p1 = 10 * p0 + buffer[i] - '0';
        if (n_digits > 1)
        {
            if (has_prime_n_digit_subset(p1, n_digits - 1, &buffer[i+1], buflen - i - 1))
            {
                //printf("<<-- true\n");
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //printf("C %d\n", p1);
            if (is_prime(p1))
            {
                //printf("<<-- p1 = %d: true\n", p1);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    //printf("<<-- false\n");
    return false;
}

static void check_minimal_prime(int n)
{
    assert(n > 0);
    if (is_prime(n))
    {
        //printf("P %d\n", n);
        char buffer[20];
        sprintf(buffer, "%d", n);
        char n_digits = strlen(buffer);
        for (int i = 1; i < n_digits; i++)
        {
            if (has_prime_n_digit_subset(0, i, buffer, n_digits))
                return;
        }

        printf("%d\n", n);              /* It's a minimal prime */
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int max = 100000;
    if (argc > 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [maximum]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (argc == 2)
    {
        max = atoi(argv[1]);
        if (max <= 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid number (%d from %s)\n", max, argv[1]);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    max /= 6;
    check_minimal_prime(2);
    check_minimal_prime(3);
    for (int c = 1; c < max; c++)
    {
        check_minimal_prime(6 * c - 1);
        check_minimal_prime(6 * c + 1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The list of numbers generated was:

```
2
3
5
7
11
19
41
61
89
409
449
499
881
991
6469
6949
9001
9049
9649
9949
60649
666649
946669
60000049
66000049
66600049
```

I didn't find any more minimal primes when checking up to 1,000,000,000.  Timing was:

```
       100    0m0.006s
      1000    0m0.006s
     10000    0m0.006s
    100000    0m0.012s
   1000000    0m0.129s
  10000000    0m2.617s
 100000000    1m8.200s
1000000000  32m34.561s
```